# Deserialize xml string in ActionScript-3?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, serialization, deserialization

**ActionScript-3**

I have an XML string that represents an object of any type (*matrix of strings and primitives*). I need to get the object / matrix out of the string.

```
// I have:
var xml: String = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><ArrayOfArrayOfAnyType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">  <ArrayOfAnyType>    <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">TEXT</anyType> ....... </anyType></ArrayOfAnyType></ArrayOfArrayOfAnyType>"

// I need:
var obj: Object = ???;
// or in the end:
var array: Array = ???;
```

- **How do I deserialize a string to object ?**
- How do I serialize any object to string ?

---

**Update:**

- I took a look at the `children()` list of `new XML(str);` object and I could `trace()` the values. So I **could** go by hand and iterate the lists to get my matrix but can't flash do that by itself ?

**Update 2:**

- I'm not using Flex
- my matrix also contains `DateTime` values, so type attribute must be used as accurate as possible.
- In order to deserialize the strings that I get I did what I wrote in the 1st update.

  - Because of namespaces I couldn't get hold of the type attribute that is **very** important for me.
  - So I killed all namespace garbage to get something like this:
  - `<anyType type="string">blah blah</anyType>`

    - I manipulated attribute-strings to kill the `"xsi:"` and `"xsd:"` garbage
  - then I just iterated and build up the matrix I wanted.
- the question in not resolved though, I wished there would be a better way of doing this.

Comment: Seems like you need to write your specific parser/translator

Comment: @Cherniv Really ? C# serialized a matrix to this string and it can easily deserialize it. Why would Flash not be able to do it ?

Comment: Are you looking for another answer, or has the issue been resolved?

Comment: @Atriace Sorry, no it's not resolved (at least not here). Maybe it's the a *strange* xml format ? But C# serialized my matrix the common way actually. For deserializing I used neither of your suggestions, see my update 2.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Flex, you can tap into [`SimpleXMLDecoder`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/xml/SimpleXMLDecoder.html)

```
function toObj(data:XML):Object {
    var xmlDoc:XMLDocument = new XMLDocument(data);
    var decoder:SimpleXMLDecoder = new SimpleXMLDecoder(true);
    return decoder.decodeXML(xmlDoc);
}

function toXML(obj:Object):XML {
    var qName:QName = new QName("root");
    var xmlDoc:XMLDocument = new XMLDocument();
    var simpleXMLEncoder:SimpleXMLEncoder = new SimpleXMLEncoder(xmlDoc);
    var xmlNode:XMLNode = simpleXMLEncoder.encodeValue(obj, qName, xmlDoc);

    return new XML(xmlDoc.toString());
}
```

If, like me, you aren't using Flex and its API, here's a pure AS3 method for converting to Object which I wrote.  This only covers going to an Object; I've never needed to serialize to a string.

```
function translateXML(xml:XML):* {
    /*  Created by Atriace: Converts XML into an Object, with nested arrays, and relevant object types.
        Useful if you find AS3's XML methods an asinine waste of time. */
    var data:XMLList = xml.children();
    var store:Object = mineAttributes(xml.attributes()), item, key:String;

    if (hasTwo(data)) { // should this be an object or array?
        for each (item in data) {  // we store arrays by the name of the array
            key = item.name();
            if (store[key] == null) {
                store[key] = new Array(); // and then the contents inside that array
            } else if (getType(store[key]) != "Array") {
                trace("store[" + key + "] = " + store[key] + ":" + getType(store[key]));
            }
            store[key].push(translateXML(item));
        }
    } else { // Assuming there were no repeating elements at the beginning, we create unique objects
        for each (item in data){ 
            key = item.name();
            if (key == null) {  // Assuming we have an encapsulated string, we add a tag called "content" with its value.
                store["content"] = item.toString();
            } else {
                store[key] = translateXML(item);  // Otherwise, we recursively loop into the nested objects.
            }
        }
    }
    return store;
}

function hasTwo(data):Boolean {
    /* Determines whether there are two of the same object name at the beginning of a list. */
    var answer:Boolean = false;
    var original;
    var i:int = 1;
    for each (var k in data) {
        if (i == 2) {
            if (original == k.name()) {
                answer = true;
            }
            break;
        } else {
            original = k.name();
        }
        i++
    }
    return answer;
}

function mineAttributes(data:XMLList):* {
    /* Returns all the attibutes of an XML node */
    var d:Object = {}, key:String, val:String;
    for each (var item in data){
        key = item.name();
        val = item;
        d[key] = val;
    }
    return d;
}

function getType(value:*):String {
    // Returns the type of object passed to it.
    var msg:String = flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName(value);
    if (msg.lastIndexOf("::") != -1) {msg = msg.split("::")[1];}
    return msg;
}
```

Comment: This class is not defined by AIR but by Flex 3.